# Why does code stops running in halfway in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

### Here is my python sample for scraping some finance data

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import dates as mdates
import datetime as dt
from mplfinance.original_flavor import candlestick_ohlc
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

# fix_yahoo_finance is used to fetch data 
import yfinance as yf
yf.pdr_override()

# input
symbol = 'AAPL'
start = '2018-01-01'
end = '2020-12-24'

# Read data 
df = yf.download(symbol,start,end)

# View Columns
df.head()
df['Absolute_Return'] = 100 * (df['Adj Close'] - df['Adj Close'].shift(1))/df['Adj Close'].shift(1)
df.head(20)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14,10))
ax1 = plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
ax1.plot(df['Adj Close'])
ax1.set_title('Stock '+ symbol +' Closing Price')
ax1.set_ylabel('Price')

ax2 = plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
ax2.plot(df['Absolute_Return'] , label='Absolute Return', color='red')
#ax2.axhline(y=0, color='blue', linestyle='--')
#ax2.axhline(y=0.5, color='darkblue')
#ax2.axhline(y=-0.5, color='darkblue')
ax2.grid()
ax2.set_ylabel('Absolute Return')
ax2.set_xlabel('Date')
ax2.legend(loc='best')
```

Problem is, if I put them in Jupyter notebook and run block by block, everything works fine. But when I put them in a normal .py file then run it, it stops in halfway, right at

```
df = yf.download(symbol,start,end)
```

Anyone please explain that for me?

Comment: Works normally for me, it doesn’t stop at the line you mentioned at-least.

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: no error at all, it's all tested, but I dont know what I missed. I use VS code to run it, and here where it stopped https://imgur.com/a/Wx5bmtL

Comment: @Jarvis Did you run it with a normal python file or a jupyter file?

Comment: As a normal python script. Add a `print` statement after the line you _believe_ it stops at and see what happens.

Comment: I'm also able to run this without issue as a normal `.py` file (though I had to add `plt.show()` at the end to get the plots to display). Verify all of your packages are up to date. If you are using an Anaconda distribution, use `conda update --all` at the anaconda prompt, otherwise you will need to pip update the appropriate packages. As this is not a reproducible issue, I'm voting to close. Also, good job making a nice reproducible question.